# A Knitted Puzzle

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

*All handmade!*

[image: handmade_knitted]

Answer is a **thematic word**. Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjFiM.png) for colorblind assistance (regions with similar colors are indicated).

Comment: wow that's pretty! Did you actually knit this?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky [Digitally](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/), of course ;-)

Comment: Could you check the bottom left part? thanks

Comment: @OmegaKrypton If you mean the yellow symbols in the bottom left, then yes, it should be correct unless my information sources are somehow wrong

Comment: For a moment I was thinking "Who is *this* new user??" Then I clicked on your profile and all became clear ;-)

Answer (score 1):

### Partial Answer, ~50% done

Part 1 - Green figures, top right

> This is a cipher based on the Dancing Man Code. Answer is HETERONYM

Part 2 - Yellow Triangles, Dots, and Crosses

> This is a cipher known as [Knight Templar](https://www.wattpad.com/668342771-codes-and-ciphers-templar-cipher). The result is UNFREEZE.

Answer (score 0):

**Partial answer**

Top left, inside the red frame

> The red thing seems like a kitchen scale to me, or a button.
>  Then, there is a checkerboard, a bee, minus a thumbs down, or dislike. [Checkerboarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkerboarding_(beekeeping)) is the only reasonable connection between all those.

Left, inside the green frame

> There is a calligraphic P, a down arrow, a wrench, and the number 4 with Roman number (IV).

Bottom right, inside the yellow frame

> The marks above the arrows look like [derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative) of the symbols.

Comment: I am pretty sure the top left bit works quite a different way, though I haven't figured out _exactly_ what it leads to.